# How to parse json when collectionView is tap

Tags: ios, json, parsing, swift3, uicollectionview

Hello I'm just wondering if there is another way to parse json data when a collection view is click and pass it to another view. This is the [API](https://overwatch-api.net//api/v1/hero/) im using. This is how I do it at the moment. This is how my class looks. First I create a closure. Then I created my hero class. Then I have my json parse function.

[image]

This is how my collectionView didSelectItemAt func looks. This is where im trying to put my json parse function, or is it better to put it in the hero class. Im new to this so I don't really know.

[image]

Not sure if I explained it well. So I'll include my viewcontroller code if needed. Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: You have already parsed your `jsonObject` inside the method `loadHeroData` of your `Hero` class. Honestly speaking it's the convenient way to do this. Don't mess up your **delegate methods** with data parsing / editing as these methods are meant to manipulate data to the `views`.

Comment: Thank you nayem :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create variable for another viewcontroller and pass the data to that variable by using didselect method

Answer (score 0):

After perform Segue you need to do following code to pass the Hero object to HeroDetail Controller:

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if segue.identifier == "HeroDetails" {

            let heroDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! HeroDetailVC
            heroDetailVC.hero = sender as! Hero

        }
     }
```

Make sure you have created Variable for Hero Object in HeroDetail Controller.

This will help you to pass the data over multiple controller using Segue Method.